# OpenPDF : iText 2.1.7 XXE vulnerability

Tags: java, pdf, reporting, birt, openpdf

Currently I am using Birt Report runtime version 4.4.2 and it internally uses iText version - 2.1.7 
I have Birt report .rptdesign files as template and using Birt Report runtime engine for dynamically create/render pdfs where data comes from database and pdf will be rendered on web browser.

As per below link there is XXE vulnerability in iText 2.1.7 version

https://www.compass-security.com/fileadmin/Datein/Research/Advisories/CSNC-2017-017_itext_xml_external_entity_attack.txt

To fix above mentioned issue I was planning to replace iText 2.1.7 jar version with OpenPDF jar. 
But looks like OpenPDF also uses classes javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory  which in turn can give XXE vulnerability

Can anyone fix this vulnerability in openPDF source code and release new version ?

Below are helpful links where Apache PDF box has fixed XXE vulnerability

https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/commit/be36ef01842885b556a4e7b40b5e2e8e7b1d2816#diff-7865264c984db3c9a6ac8471b0a4d414

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in OpenPDF 1.0.5. Therefore I recommend for people using iText 2.1.7 to upgrade to the latest version of OpenPDF.

https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF/releases/tag/1.0.5